# how to check if my checkbox is checked or not. Ad save it to LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im new to programming, just a junior for now.
I have list of checkboxes. And when I uncheck a checkbox, I want unchecked checkbox to be saved in my local storage. Here is my code snipped, what im doing wrong? Cant fully understand what i wrote. Thank you

```
export default () => {
  const [isDefaultChecked, setDefaultChecked] = useState(true);
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState();
  const [isColumn, setColumn] = useState(true);
  const [hiddenColumns, setHiddenColumns] = useState([]);
  const [Checked, setIsChecked] = useState([]);
const onCheckboxChange = (key: string, value: boolean) => {
    const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hiddenColumns"));
     // here im trying to check if value = to
    if (value) {
       const column = hiddenColumns.find((item) => item.value == key);
       const filtered = hiddenColumns.filter(
         (item) => item.key !== column.key
       )
       setHiddenColumns(filtered);
    
       if (!value) {
       setHiddenColumns([...hiddenColumns, { 'label': key } ]);
     }

    localStorage.setItem("hiddenColumns", JSON.stringify(key));
   }
  };
return(
          <div>
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked={isDefaultChecked}
              label="Delivery Methods"
              onChange={(value) => onCheckboxChange("delieveryMethods", value)}
            />
          </div>
)
```

Comment: Looks like you read in from localStorage an array of hidden column values (as `array`) and never reference it again, then check `value` and do some stuff based on it's truthy/falsey-ness, and then store into localStorage the key value `"deliveryMethods"`. It's not really clear what role you are expecting localStorage to play here. Looks like you are also missing a closing `}` for the first `if` statement, so it also isn't clear what the conditional scope is for it there.

Comment: got it, thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (!value) {
   setHiddenColumns([...hiddenColumns, { 'label': key } ]);
 }

localStorage.setItem("hiddenColumns", JSON.stringify(key));
```

You are saving a single key to localStorage, to be consistent with your code, you must save the entire array again.

Now, you hiddenColumns array seems to be a collection of { label } where label is the key.
Also, it stores the values that are hidden only. So, on your onCheckboxChange, if value is true, it means that you should add the key of the checkbox to the array and if value is false, you should take it out. The following codes achieves that

```
const onCheckboxChange = (key: string, value: boolean) => {
    if (value) setHiddenColumns(hiddenColumns => [...hiddenColumns, { label: key }]);
    else setHiddenColumns(hiddenColumns.filter(x => x.label !== key));
  };
```

after that, you can add a useEffect hook that would be triggered when hiddenColumns array changes that would maintain your localStorage sync with hiddenColumns array

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("hiddenColumns", JSON.stringify(hiddenColumns));
}, [hiddenColumns]);
```

Comment: I combined your code (with some changes) with my own, and it worked somehow. Thank you! :D